# how django filter(string__icontains) can iterate through a list?

Tags: django

I have a list of strings as below:

```
items = ['apple', 'shoes', 'milk', 'blue', 'black', 'phone']
```

and a field in my django model field which has strings separated by `(,)comma` like below:

```
tag = 'apple, phone, tenis, telvision'
```

I want to filter those posts which have at least one item in their tag field which also listed in the given list.

This is what I tried but does not give me the result and not sure if it's efficient:

```
posts = []
for item in items:
    posts.append(Post.objects.filter(tag__icontains=item))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think your tag field takes tag = 'apple, phone, tenis, telvision' as a string.
you can do this,

```
posts = []
items = ['apple', 'shoes', 'milk', 'blue', 'black', 'phone']
instance = Post.objects.all()
for item in items:
    for data in instance:
        if item in data.tag.split(','):
            posts.append(data)
            break
```

you will get all instance of your model which contains 'items'
or get single object of model and do
posts = []

```
data= Post.objects.get(id=1)
for item in items:
    if item in data.tag.split(','):
        posts.append(data)
        break
```